# InstallShield - Detect USB 3.0 Ports

Tags: installscript, installshield-2012

I am building a InstallShield InstallScript project.  How can i find out if the Target machine has any USB 3.0 ports.  My installer should abort if there are no USB 3.0 ports on the target machine.

Thanks